# Is it possible to choose default cmake preset configuration from the vscode devcontainer

Tags: visual-studio-code, cmake, devcontainer, cmake-presets

I have two devcontainers defined for my c++ project, one for gcc and one for clang, each based on a different container source.

[image]

The clang container is defined so

```
// For format details, see https://aka.ms/devcontainer.json. For config options, see the
// README at: https://github.com/devcontainers/templates/tree/main/src/debian
{
    "name": "mw-clang",
    "image": "dockerhub.moduleworks.com:443/devops/docker-images/linux-clang-toolkit",


    // Configure tool-specific properties.
    // "customizations": {},
    "customizations": {
        "vscode": {"extensions": ["ms-vscode.cmake-tools"]}
    }


}
```

However I have two different cmake presets, again one for gcc and one for clang. I've figured out how to tell vscode that I need cmake tools for each container.

[image]

Is it also possible in each dev container to specific the CMakePreset which is most suitable for that container and also add other custom CMake flags?

Comment: (preface: I'm not familiar with devcontainer setup). [docs](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cmake-tools/blob/main/docs/cmake-settings.md#cmake-settings). I'm not aware of a setting for specifying a default preset to use. There are settings currently for setting configure args (`cmake.configureArgs`). see also `cmake.buildArgs`, `cmake.configureEnvironment`, `cmake.configureSettings`.

Comment: I googled "`site:github.com/microsoft/vscode-cmake-tools/issues default preset setting`" and didn't see anything that looked promising in the top search results. All I saw was https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cmake-tools/issues/2711. I assume you'll need something like a VS Code setting for selecting default CMake configure and build presets to use? (in which case you might need/want to [create a feature-request issue ticket](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cmake-tools/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&template=bugreport.yml))